# Cannot use function cpuset_create from shared C library <cpuset.h>

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries

I am trying to port a C project from a CentOS 7 (Core) to an Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa) system. The program compiles and runs without problem on CentOS and also compiles without error on the Ubuntu system. However, when I try to execute the program on Ubuntu, I encounter the  following error:

```
ERROR aff_prog_alloc @aff-executor.c:299 => cpuset_create: No such file or directory
```

The function `cpuset_create` is part of the `<cpuset.h>` library and the flag `-lcpuset` is included when compiling. The following is the output from the ldd command, showing the path for the `<cpuset.h>` library on our Ubuntu system:

```
$ ldd ./aff-executor
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffed97eb000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f8c179d5000)
    libcpuset.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcpuset.so.1 (0x00007f8c177c8000)
    libbitmask.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbitmask.so.1 (0x00007f8c175c4000)
    libnuma.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnuma.so.1 (0x00007f8c175b7000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f8c175ac000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f8c173ba000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f8c17a22000)
```

I verified that the library actually exists at this location:

```
$ll /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcpuset.*
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 67952 Nov 21  2016 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcpuset.a
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    18 Nov 21  2016 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcpuset.so -> libcpuset.so.1.1.0
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    18 Nov 21  2016 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcpuset.so.1 -> libcpuset.so.1.1.0
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 52232 Nov 21  2016 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcpuset.so.1.1.0
```

Can anyone help with identifying why `cpuset_create` does not work on this system despite it having the correct syntax and inputs?

==================================
Update/Additional Info

The following code is what I need to use for my project. Everything works fine until the `cpuset_create` function which has been returning `-1`. I checked this program on a different Ubuntu (16.04.5 LTS (Xenial Xerus)) and it executed without problem on it, with `cpuset_create` returning the expected `0`.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include<stdio.h>
#include <bitmask.h>
#include <cpuset.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include<numa.h>

typedef struct cpuset        cpuset_t;
struct bitmask * get_mems_all(void);

/* return a bitmask describing all the available memory nodes */
struct bitmask * get_mems_all(void)
{
    struct bitmask *ret;

    if (numa_available() != -1){
        printf("NUMA is available\n");
        return numa_get_mems_allowed();
    }

    ret = bitmask_alloc(cpuset_mems_nbits());
    printf("ret: %p\n",ret );
    if (!ret)
        printf("bitmask_alloc err");
    bitmask_setbit(ret,0);
    return ret;
}

int main(){

    int err;
    struct bitmask  *mem_bm;

    mem_bm=get_mems_all();
    printf("mem_bm: %p\n",mem_bm );

    numa_bitmask_clearbit(mem_bm, 1);
    numa_bitmask_setbit(mem_bm,0);
    char buff[256];
    bitmask_displaylist(buff, sizeof(buff), mem_bm);
    printf("buff: %s\n",buff );

    printf("mem_bm: %p\n",mem_bm );

    printf("cpuset lib version: %d\n",cpuset_version() );

    cpuset_t *cpuset=cpuset_alloc();
    printf("cpuset: %p\n",cpuset );

    err = cpuset_setmems(cpuset,mem_bm);
    printf("err cpuset_setmems: %d\n", err);

    char* path="/AFF_1000/";
    err = cpuset_create(path, cpuset);
    printf("err cpuset_create: %d\n", err);

    return 0;
}
```

Compilation:

```
gcc -Wall -O2 -std=gnu99 test.c -o test -lcpuset -lbitmask -lnuma
```

Output on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa):

```
$./test
NUMA is available
mem_bm: 0x55a34b2ac120
buff: 0
mem_bm: 0x55a34b2ac120
cpuset lib version: 3
cpuset: 0x55a34b2ac1d0
err cpuset_setmems: 0
err cpuset_create: -1
```

Expected output (this is from Ubuntu 16.04LTS (Xenial Xerus)):

```
$./test
NUMA is available
mem_bm: 0x1c39670
buff: 0
mem_bm: 0x1c39670
cpuset lib version: 3
cpuset: 0x1c396b0
err cpuset_setmems: 0
err cpuset_create: 0

$cset set -l
cset: 
         Name       CPUs-X    MEMs-X Tasks Subs Path
 ------------ ---------- - ------- - ----- ---- ----------
         root       0-63 y     0-1 y   500    2 /
     AFF_1000      ***** n       0 n     0    0 /AFF_1000
       system       0-63 n       0 n   349    0 /system
```

However, I am unable to run the same program as root on Ubuntu 16.04 as well. I get the following error:

```
sudo ./test
./test: error while loading shared libraries: libcpuset.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? I do not know if this last problem is related to why my program won't run on the Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: pls include also code where you are calling cpuset_create. Also is that Ubuntu virtualised or not?

Comment: The message is _not_ complaining about the location of the `cpuset` shared library. It is that `create_cpuset` is failing. In other words, some file/directory is missing. Could it be that `/dev/cpuset` does not exist and/or is not mounted correctly? You may wish to run your program under `strace` so you can see what files/directories it tries to access.

Comment: ENOENT = "No such file or directory" is returned when: [Attempted cpuset_create() in a parent cpuset that doesn’t exist.](https://man.cx/libcpuset(3))

Comment: @CraigEstey I added some additional information about the problem with ```cpuset_create```. You were correct about it not being a shared library problem. I am able to use other functions from this library but not ```cpuset_create```. I have attached the corresponding code in the post.

Comment: @Risinek I have added a snippet of code to the post. However, I am not able to determine if the server I am working on has a virtualized ubuntu.

Comment: @dratenik It doesn't seem like the error is ENOENT. The error code being returned is ```-1```. I added some more information to the post if that would help. Thanks

Comment: Yes, [On error, these routines return -1 and set errno](http://www.servu.org/mirror/old/mirrors.bufferoverflow.xyz/oss.sgi.com/projects/cpusets/download/libcpuset.html#basic-cpuset-library-functions). It seems that now you updated your question with a different problem, so it may not have a single answer. One problem per question please.