# Shared library disparity between Linux CentOS 7 and Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, shared-libraries, centos7

I am porting a project written in C from a CentOS 7 (Core) to an Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa) system. The project relies heavily on the `<cpuset.h>` library, and compiles and executes correctly on the CentOS system. However, when I try to use functions from cpuset.h on the Ubuntu system, I get 'undefined reference' errors.

The following code, stored in file `test.c`, compiles and runs correctly on CentOS:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include<stdio.h>
#include <cpuset.h>

int main(){

    int x = cpuset_version();
    printf("cpuset lib version: %d\n",x );

    return 0;
}
```

How I compile:
`gcc -Wall -O2 -std=gnu99 -g -lcpuset test.c -o test`

Output:

```
[xxxx@CentOS]$ ./test 
cpuset lib version: 3
```

However, when I try to compile the same `test.c` file on the Ubuntu system, I get this error:

```
xxxx@Ubuntu:$ gcc -Wall -O2 -std=gnu99 -g -lcpuset test.c -o test
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccpxlk4F.o: in function `main':
test.c:8: undefined reference to `cpuset_version'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Furthermore, this is not limited to the `<cpuset.h>` library. I tried to use a simple function from `<pthread.h>` and it also gave me the same error. Can anyone help with identifying why I cannot use shared libraries on the Ubuntu system? Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a followon to your previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66535986/cannot-use-function-cpuset-create-from-shared-c-library-cpuset-h But, it looks like a regression. In the previous question, you _could_ link to the library [and the error was a runtime error from the `cpuset_create` call]. Now, you're having trouble linking to the library. But, since it compiles, this means that `cpuset.h` exists and is accessible. So, what directory? For pthreads, did you add `-lpthread` as _last_ arg. Try using `find`: (e.g.) `find / -xdev -name '*pthread*'` [also for `*cpuset*`]

Comment: Things are scanned _in order_ of the command line. Put `-lcpuset` as the _last_ argument. As you have it, the lib _is_ scanned but nothing is pulled in because it will only do so _after_ the compilation of `test.c` which _hasn't_ occurred yet when `-lcpuset` is scanned.

Comment: @CraigEstey: Exactly! So, Shivam Kundan, use `gcc -Wall -O2 -std=gnu99 -g test.c -lcpuset -o test`.  In Makefile terms, `$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $^` when compiling but not linking, and `$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ $(LDFLAGS) -o $@` when linking (or compiling and linking, as you are now).

Comment: This would have failed on CentOS also.

Comment: Thank you for the help, @CraigEstey. The solution was indeed to move -lcpuset to the end of the command.Since this was a tangential question to my previous post, I am marking this one as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since OP's issue is wrong order of parameters to GCC (many guides do show an incorrect order!), as discussed in the comments to the question, I believe showing a minimal `Makefile` to handle these is warranted:

```Makefile
CC      := gcc
CFLAGS  := -Wall -O2 -g
LDFLAGS := -lcpuset
TARGETS := test

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(TARGETS)

clean:
    rm -f *.o $(TARGETS)

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $^

test: test.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ $(LDFLAGS) -o $@
```

Note that the indentation in Makefiles must use <kbd>Tab</kbd>s and not spaces.  Since this forum converts <kbd>Tab</kbd>s to spaces, you will need to fix the above makefile, for example by running `sed -e 's|^  *|\t|' -i Makefile`.

If you want to compile say `foo.c` directly to an executable, the recipe is

```makefile
foo: foo.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ $(LDFLAGS) -o $@
```

You only need to run `make` (it defaults to using the Makefile in the current directory, and the default target is the first one, above the one named `all`), to recompile the TARGETS (here, `test`, but you can supply more by just adding them space-separated to the line).

You can also run `make clean test` to rebuild `test` from "scratch", i.e. removing all temporary files and all targets first.

You can override variables like `CFLAGS` by simply supplying them on the command line; for example, `make CFLAGS="-Wall -Wextra -Os" clean all` to recompile everything with different compilation flags.